# How to solve "TZInfo::DataSourceNotFound: tzinfo-data is not present."when I do a rails db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, circleci

We are implementing CI using CircleCI.
I get an error about tzinfo-data in the following run, and I can't get to the test.
I wrote a run to install tzinfo-data, but it didn't work. I'm completely stuck.

config.yml

```yaml
- run:
    name: Database setup
    command: |
      bundle exec rails db:create
      bundle exec rails db:migrate
```

error

```
rake aborted!
TZInfo::DataSourceNotFound: tzinfo-data is not present. Please add gem 'tzinfo-data' to your Gemfile and run bundle install
```

config.yml:

```yaml
version: 2.1
orbs:
  ruby: circleci/ruby@1.1.2

jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: cimg/ruby:2.6.5
    working_directory: ~/myapp/web
    steps:
      - checkout:
          path: ~/myapp
      - restore_cache:
          name: bundle install restore
          keys:
            - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "Gemfile.lock" }}
            - v1-dependencies-
      - run:
          name: default mysql client install
          command: |
            sudo apt update
            sudo apt-get install default-mysql-client
            sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
      - run:
          name: bundle Install
          command: bundle check --path=vendor/bundle || bundle install --jobs=4 --retry=3 --path vendor/bundle
      - save_cache:
          name: bundle install save
          paths:
            - ./vendor/bundle
          key: v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "Gemfile.lock" }}
  test:
    docker:
      - image: cimg/ruby:2.6.5
      - image: circleci/mysql:5.7
        environment:
          DB_DATABASE: app_test
          DB_PASSWORD: password
          DB_USER: root
          TZ: "Asia/Tokyo"
    environment:
      BUNDLE_JOBS: "3"
      BUNDLE_RETRY: "3"
      APP_DATABASE_HOST: "127.0.0.1"
      RAILS_ENV: test
      TZ: "Asia/Tokyo"
    working_directory: ~/myapp/web
    steps:
      - checkout:
          path: ~/myapp
      - restore_cache:
          name: bundle install restore
          key: v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "Gemfile.lock" }}
      - run:
          name: default mysql client install
          command: |
            sudo apt update
            sudo apt-get install default-mysql-client
            sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
      - run:
          name: bundle install
          command: bundle check --path=vendor/bundle || bundle install --path vendor/bundle --clean --jobs 4 --retry 3
      - run:
          name: Database setup
          command: |
            bundle exec rails db:create
            bundle exec rails db:migrate
      - run:
          name: Echo Test
          command: echo "CircleCI Test"
      - run:
          name: test
          command: bundle exec rake test

workflows:
  version: 2
  build_and_test:
    jobs:
      - build
      - test:
          requires:
            - build
```

Gemfile:

```rb
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.6.5'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.3', '>= 6.0.3.7'
# Use mysql as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2', '>= 0.4.4'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 4.1'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
# Transpile app-like JavaScript. Read more: https://github.com/rails/webpacker
gem 'webpacker', '~> 4.0'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Active Storage variant
# gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

# jQuery
gem "jquery-rails"
gem 'rails-i18n', '~> 6'
# enum i18n
gem "enum_help"
gem "config"
gem 'faraday'

gem 'acts_as_paranoid', '~> 0.6.0'

gem 'http-cookie'

gem 'kaminari'

gem 'devise'
gem 'devise_token_auth'
gem 'devise-security'
gem 'devise-two-factor', '~> 3.1'

# AWS
gem 'aws-sdk'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.2', require: false

gem 'composite_primary_keys'

gem 'clamav-client', require: 'clamav/client'

gem 'wovnrb'

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of web drivers to run system tests with browsers
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

##### I tried(1)

I tried to add `tzinfo` to the Gemfile as follows, but I get the same error.

```rb
# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
gem 'tzinfo', '1.2.9'
```

↓
bundle install
↓
Gemfile.lock

```
DEPENDENCIES
...
  tzinfo (= 1.2.9)
  tzinfo-data
```

↓
Run with circleCI
↓
Same error

##### I tried(2)

Install the tzinfo gem as run
config.yml

```
- run:
    name: tzinfo install
    command: |
      gem install tzinfo -v "~> 1.2.9"
      gem install tzinfo-data
```

↓
Run with circleCI
↓
Same error

Comment: Did you run `bundle install` after adding the entries to the gemfile?

Comment: @dbugger: In the local environment, when I added gem 'tzinfo', '1.2.9' to the Gemfile and did a bundleinstall, tzinfo (= 1.2.9) was added to the DEPENDENCIES section of Gemfile.lock ( (tzinfo_data is also in the DEPENDENCIES section as well)

Answer (score -1):

After the bundle install, I added the following and was able to run

```
- run:
  name: RUN apt install tzdata
  command: sudo apt install tzdata
```